# How to apply or change color on navbar (menu) items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to figure out how to get an image to the right of my navbar. And also have an image to the right of my navbar once its been collapsed.

Also, I cant figure out how to make my navbar be fixed to the top of the page when scrolling. Ive tried navbar-fixed-top, but to no avail.

Im using bootstrap

Here is my code..

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 2em;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: static !important;
}

.navbar-nav,
.navbar-nav li,
.navbar-nav li a {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-right: 0em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header ">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbarNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
        <br/><br/>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CALCULATORS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Any and all help is MUCH appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean image on the right. Place where? On the navbar?

Comment: If any of the solutions helped you, you can rate it or mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because bootstrap's CSS is `overriding your own custom CSS`. There's a simple workaround though, you can just implement `your own ID or class on the navbar-nav` as I have demonstrated below with the ID `"links"` and apply the CSS on links instead.

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 2em;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: static !important;
}


#links a {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: red;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-right: 0em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header ">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbarNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
        <br/><br/>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="links">
          
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CALCULATORS</a></li>
          
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed header,Page scroll and navigation item color changed on scroll.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Scroll Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting">
                <img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;"
                     src="//www.google.com/favicon.ico">
            </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```